# Swing components freezing (Java)

Tags: java, swing, timer, components, event-dispatch-thread

I've coded a complex Snake game using Swing components.
I have a timer (call it moveRate) that calls repaint(); every x ms (x is changed during game and never goes below 50).
Now for the issue: I'm successful playing like 4 min or so before the whole frame freezes.

### MoveRate class:

```
class MoveRate extends Timer{
private Date dateCreated=new Date();
private long timeLast=0;

public MoveRate(){
super(190, null);
dateCreated=new Date();
addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if(getWidth()>0 && getHeight()>0){
    if(points.get(0).x+HOPS>getWidth() || points.get(0).x<0 ||
        points.get(0).y+HOPS>getHeight() || points.get(0).y<0)
      if(!crosswalls && !cheats){
        moveRate.stop();
        prizeRate.stop();
        GameOver();
      }
      else{
        if(points.get(0).y<0)
          points.get(0).y=sp.getHeight()-HOPS;
        else if(points.get(0).y+HOPS>sp.getHeight())
          points.get(0).y=0;
        else if(points.get(0).x<0)
          points.get(0).x=sp.getWidth()-HOPS;
        else
          points.get(0).x=0;
      }
    timeLast=(System.currentTimeMillis()-dateCreated.getTime())/SECONDS;
    score+=timeLast*(200/moveRate.getDelay());                          
  }
  if(prize!=null)
    if(points.get(0).x==prize.x && points.get(0).y==prize.y){
      int newX = points.get(points.size()-1).x-(points.get(points.size()-1).x - points.get(points.size()-2).x);
      int newY = points.get(points.size()-1).y-(points.get(points.size()-1).y - points.get(points.size()-2).y);
      points.add(new Point(newX, newY));
      if(moveRate.getDelay()>50)
        moveRate.setDelay(moveRate.getDelay()-5);
      prize.createPrize(PU_NONE);
      prizeRate.restart();
      score+=timeLast*20*eatmultiplier;
    }
  if(powerup!=null)
    if(points.get(0).x==powerup.x && points.get(0).y==powerup.y){
      int newX = points.get(points.size()-1).x-(points.get(points.size()-1).x - points.get(points.size()-2).x);
      int newY = points.get(points.size()-1).y-(points.get(points.size()-1).y - points.get(points.size()-2).y);
      //points.add(new Point(newX, newY)); //if powerup should increase size
      powerUpPerform(powerup.getType());
      if(moveRate.getDelay()>50)
        moveRate.setDelay(moveRate.getDelay()-5);
      //powerUpRate.restart();
      score+=timeLast*20*eatmultiplier;
      powerup=null;
    }
  p.setScore(score);
  repaint();
}
});
}
}
```

Basically MoveRate is responsible for animation aswell "eat moves" for prizes & powerups and checks for Game Over situations.
Some other notes:

I thought this has something to do with threads which I haven't learned yet so I added this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
moveRate=new MoveRate();
moveRate.start();
powerUpRate.start();
prizeRate.start();
}
}).start();
```

Frame still freezes.
System.gc(); doesn't work neither if I time it every 30 seconds.

Be easy with me because I'm junior student with Java :>

**EDIT**
I've tried to reproduce the "bug" by making the snake longer (much longer - using my final int SNAKE_INITIAL_LENGTH=200). doesn't seem to have any effect on the problem.

Comment: For starters, don't extend `Timer`. That's completely unnatural.

Comment: This is my knowledge so far. It ain't great but I'm learning. Is there a solution to leave it the way it is without changing librarys or is it inevitable?

Comment: a gui freezing typically means that you are accessing the view and/or its properties off the EDT - so first step is to learn about concurrency in swing (see the link in the swing tag wiki) After that, best to show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Link please? cant seem to find it.

Comment: click the info tab ...

Comment: Start with [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), cited in the [tag:swing] tag under _learn more_.

Comment: Ok I've used System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
to determine if moveRate is EDT and now that I know it is how can it help me?

Comment: Design is very bad. However concerning the main cause. What is the moveRate.getDelay() value after this 4 minutes of your play?

Comment: I've set it to 50. It doesn't get lower than that (handled by if-statement).